# Derivative of the inner product of Jacobi fields and it's derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold of constant sectional curvature equal to $1$. Let $J_{\xi}(t)$  and $J_{\eta}(t)$ be two jacobi fields. Then I would like to see if it's true $\frac{d}{dt}(\langle J_{\xi}(t), J_{\eta}(t)\rangle + \langle \dot J_{\xi}(t), \dot J_{\eta}(t)\rangle)=0$.

I was able to do it when the jacobi fields involved are normal and along a normalized geodesic, since the jacobi equation will tells us $ J''=-J$.  But for more general jacobi fields I don't know how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have tried decomposing my jacobi fields as $J_{\xi}(t)=J_{\xi}^{\perp}(t)+a_{\xi}t\dot \gamma+ b_{\xi}\dot \gamma$ and $J_{\eta}(t)=J_{\eta}^{\perp}(t)+a_{\eta}t\dot \gamma+ b_{\eta}\dot \gamma$. Then we have that $\dot J_{\xi}(t)= \dot J_{\xi}^{\perp}(t)+a_{\xi}\dot \gamma$ and $\dot J_{\eta}= \dot J_{\eta}^{\perp}(t)+a_{\eta}\dot \gamma$. Then we have that

$\langle \dot J_{\xi}(t), J_{\eta}(t) \rangle = \langle \dot J_{\xi}^{\perp} , J_{\eta}^{\perp}\rangle + a_{\xi}a_{\eta}t\langle \dot \gamma, \dot \gamma \rangle + a_{\xi}b_{\eta}\langle \dot \gamma , \dot \gamma \rangle $

$\langle  J_{\xi}(t), \dot J_{\eta}(t) \rangle = \langle  J_{\xi}^{\perp} , \dot J_{\eta}^{\perp}\rangle + a_{\xi}a_{\eta}t\langle \dot \gamma, \dot \gamma \rangle + a_{\xi}b_{\eta}\langle \dot \gamma , \dot \gamma \rangle $

and

$J''_{\xi}(t)= -R(\dot \gamma , J_{xi})\dot \gamma$ tells us that $J''_{\xi}(t)= -\langle \dot \gamma , \dot \gamma \rangle J^{\perp}_{\xi}$

But with this I don't see how I can get that $\frac{d}{dt}(\langle J_{\xi}(t), J_{\eta}(t)\rangle + \langle \dot J_{\xi}(t), \dot J_{\eta}(t)\rangle)=0$.

Comment: If $T$ is the velocity vector of the constant speed geodesic, then any Jacobi field is of the form $J + (at+b)T$, where $a$, $b$ are constants and $J$ is normal to the geodesic. Your calculation extends easily to this case.

Comment: Did you try calculating the derivative of $\langle J_\xi,J_\eta\rangle + \langle \dot{J}_\xi,\dot{J}_\eta\rangle$?

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again. I am struggling with the same problem trying to see how this condition implies the geodesic flow to be an isometry. Have you had success on proving that?